# How do I show that the definition of Sobolev–Slobodeckij spaces $W^{s,p}(\Omega)$ coincides with the classical one when $s$ is integer.

Tags: sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

For any nonnegative real number $s$ and $1<p<\infty$, the Sobolev–Slobodeckij space $W^{s,p}(\Omega)$ is defined as in the following link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Sobolev%E2%80%93Slobodeckij_spaces

Here, we assume for brevity that $\Omega$ is either a bounded region in some Euclidean space with smooth boundaries or a compact Riemannian manifold.

I think that when $s$ is an integer, such Sobolev–Slobodeckij spaces $W^{s,p}(\Omega)$ must coincide with the "classical Sobolev space" defined in terms of weak derivatives. Of course, the norms from each definition must be equivalent as well.

However, I cannot find a reference explicitly dealing with this issue.

Comment: The definition you quoted starts with "Let $s>0$ be not an integer..."

Comment: @Feng  wait....I need to check again...I took it for granted that $s$ can be extended to integer cases as well.

Answer (score 6):

I cannot click on your link because I am traveling but I suppose you are referring to the definition
$$
|u|_{W^{s,p}(\Omega)}^p = \int_{\Omega^{2}} \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{d+sp}} \,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y
\\
\|u\|_{W^{s,p}(\Omega)}^p = \|u\|_{L^p}^p + |u|_{W^{s,p}(\Omega)}^p
$$
with this definition, the limit $s\to 1$ does not give the $W^{1,p}$ norm, but you can get it by multiplying the norm by the right factor.

I invite you to read the paper "*How to recognize constant functions. Connections with Sobolev spaces*" by H. Brezis. In particular, Equation (44) there shows that
$$
p\,(1-s)\,|u|_{W^{s,p}(\Omega)}^p \to C_{d,p}\,|u|_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}^p
$$
when $s\to 1$. If you do not put the factor $1-s$, then $|u|_{W^{s,p}(\Omega)}^p$ converges to
$$
\int_{\Omega^2} \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{d+p}} \,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y
$$
but the only functions for which the above quantity is bounded are the constant functions (that's Corollary $1$ of the same paper).

---

**Going deeper.**

- There are other equivalent definitions of the fractional norms. Actually, they can be defined as real interpolation spaces of Sobolev spaces. Then there is a general result by M. Milmann "*Notes on limits of Sobolev spaces and the continuity of interpolation scales*" about the factor to put in front of the interpolated spaces when you reach the boundary spaces.
- The constant $C_{d,p}$ can be computed more exactly as $C_{d,p} = \frac{2\,\omega_{d+p}}{\omega_{p+1}}$ where $\omega_d = \frac{2\,\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(d/2)}$. In my recent paper [arxiv.org:2210.03013](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2210.03013.pdf), I had fun finding the constant to get a norm that is compatible on all the sides $p\to\infty$, $s\to 0$, $s\to 1$, $p=2$, then you can define (Remark 2.1 of the mentioned paper, in dimension $2d$) the seminorm
  $$
  |u|_{W^{s,p}(\Omega)}^p = C_{d,s,p} \int_{\!\Omega^2} \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{d+sp}} \,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y
  $$
  with $C_{d,s,p} = \frac{p\,|\omega_{-2s}|}{2\,\omega_{d+sp}} \left(\frac{\pi\,\omega_{p+1}}{s^{p/2-1}}\right)^s$.
- One could use second order differences instead of first order differences in the definition of the seminorm, that is replace $u(x+z)-u(x)$ by $u(x+z)+u(x-z)-2\,u(x)$. Then the limiting norm in the limit $s\to 1$ is the Besov space $B^s_{p,p}$. And indeed, for $s$ not an integer, $B^s_{p,p} = W^{s,p}$, but not anymore for integers. Except in the case $p=2$. In this case, by the Remark 2.5 of my above mentioned paper, one finds in dimension $d$
  $$
  |u|_{B^1_{2,2}}^2 = \frac{2\ln(4)\,\omega_d}{d} \,\|\nabla u\|_{L^2}^2
  $$
  where the first seminorm is the one with the double difference, that is
  $$
  |u|_{B^1_{2,2}}^2 = \int_{\!\Omega^2} \frac{|u(x+z)+u(x-z)-2u(x)|^2}{|z|^{d+2s}} \,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d z.
  $$